# Using linux perf and PEBS to sample memory accesses in a program

Tags: linux, caching, memory, instrumentation, perf

I've been trying to use the linux perf tool to sample the memory accesses in my program. Specifically, I'm using the `perf mem` command to instrument the loads in the program:

```
perf mem -t load rec myprogram
perf mem -t load rep
```

However, I would like to increase the sampling frequency and collect more samples. But I did not find any option for the `perf mem` command that controls the sampling frequency.

**Questions**

1. Is there an option that would let me control the sampling frequency when running `perf mem`?
2. What's the default sampling frequency?
3. Is there a better option that `perf mem` to instrument the memory accesses in the program? I'm specifically looking for the following bits of data for each of the sampled load operations - (i) Target data address (ii) And whether the load resulted in an L1/L2/LLC cache hit or not.

Comment: PEBS is good variant to record memory access addresses, but still complex. There is another way (not so exact) - simulate cache accesses with binary instrumentation; the tool for it - valgrind's cachegrind http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html. It simulates own cache hierarchy with caches not same as in real hardware; and it is slow (10-20x slowdown). But using of instrumentation it has all data access addresses.

Comment: PS: according to code of recent `perf mem record` implementation: http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/tools/perf/builtin-mem.c#L23 it may pass options to the `perf record` (via rec_argv `cmd_record(i, rec_argv, NULL);`). If it refuses to do so, you can hack perf's sources, adding new options to `mem_options` in builtin-mem.

Answer (score 1):

1- have you tried the `-F` option used to specify the average sampling rate in samples per sec (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record) ?

2- According to the wiki (link above) *"The perf tool defaults to the average rate. It is set to 1000Hz, or 1000 samples/sec."*

3- I think `perf mem` provides all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks Manuel! I tried the `-c` option of `perf record` [to control sampling period]. However, I didn't find a difference in the number of samples collected even as I varied -c parameter a lot. For example:

(i) **perf record -e instructions:u -c 2000 ./a.out** # To sample every 2000 ins
    **perf report -D -i perf.data | fgrep RECORD_SAMPLE | wc -l** # No. of samples collected = **17506**

(ii) **perf record -e instructions:u -c 10000 ./a.out** # To sample every 10000 ins
    **perf report -D -i perf.data | fgrep RECORD_SAMPLE | wc -l** # No. of samples collected = **17401**

Comment: jithinpt, do check output of `dmesg` and `sysctl -a |grep perf`. There is some auto-tuning in perf - it will not allow you to generate too many profiling events (sometimes it is limited just to several kHz; it means that on 3GHz CPU you can't profile more often than around 1 million cycles or 1 million instruction) and profiling should use no more 25% of CPU by default. Superuser `root` can change limits.